# SQL Wrong syntax near 'END'

Tags: c#, sql, syntax

Ill try create a some rule from account creation method. And see You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

```
string query1 = "IF account.char_count_max > 0 THEN INSERT INTO 
playercharacter(id, connection_ID) VALUES((SELECT id FROM account WHERE 
connection_ID='" + connectionID + "'), (SELECT connection_ID FROM account 
WHERE 
connection_ID='" + connectionID + "')) END";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query1, 
MySQL.mySQLsettings.connection);
try
{             
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery is normally used for executing INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements directly, and not as part of an IF. Bearing this in mind I suggest you change your code to:

```
if (accountCharCount > 0)
{
    string query1 = "INSERT INTO playercharacter(id, connection_ID) VALUES((SELECT id FROM account WHERE connection_ID='" + connectionID + "'), (SELECT connection_ID FROM account WHERE connection_ID='" + connectionID + "'))";
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query1, MySQL.mySQLsettings.connection))
    {
        try
        {             
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

You thus need a previous call to the database to get accountCharCount (account.char_count_max). Alternatively, you could put all the SQL into a stored procedure and then call that using a single SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery.

By the way, you should really be using a MySqlParameter for connection_ID, and not a literal string; this will protect you against SQL injection attacks, and is a good habit to get into.